# Getting centroids for multiple lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, line, centroids, geometry-conversion, point-creation

Is there a possibility to get the centroid of each line?

[image]

When using `Vector > Analysis Tools > Mean Coordinates` I always get a centroid of the whole lines. What I need is the centroid of each line without having to select individual lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In tool ["Mean coordinate(s)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#mean-coordinate-s) from the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) use Unique `"ID"` field.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

In the [Field Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator), create a new *String* field and set the length to be something high like `99`. Then use the expression:

```
geomToWKT(centroid($geometry))
```

This should give centroid coordinate values like `Point (-4.28930643 55.86506837)`.

Comment: @MaFo - Most welcome, glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polyline layer called *'lines_test2'*, see image below.

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible * to get the centroid of each line*.

```sql
SELECT
    "id",
    st_centroid(geometry) AS geom
FROM
    "lines_test2"
```

The output point layer with its attribute table will look like:

[image: result]

However, keep in mind the difference between Centroid | Midpoint | Center, more details here: [Getting the line middle point with SQL in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333228/getting-the-line-middle-point-with-sql-in-qgis).

---

**References:**

- [Creating point at line end using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347762/creating-point-at-line-end-using-qgis)
- [Difference between Mean Coordinates and Polygon Centroids tools in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291980/difference-between-mean-coordinates-and-polygon-centroids-tools-in-qgis)
- [Calculating mean distribution of point locations using field values in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/424462/calculating-mean-distribution-of-point-locations-using-field-values-in-qgis)