# Getting the line middle point with SQL in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

Using SQL in a Virtual Layer is it possible to get the midpoint of a line on the line?

I have tried [Finding middle point (midpoint) of line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/finding-middle-point-midpoint-of-line-in-qgis/58089#58089) but got an error

[image: error]

I also tried

```
SELECT road, st_centroid(geometry) as Mid_Point
FROM CSC_Roads
GROUP BY road
```

but these points are then not always on the line.

[image: example]

I'd also like the final value to be formatted as `(x,y)`-tuple as I need to display the value in a table.

[image: desired_output]

So this should be

```
Airport      | 507889.784, 8044651.312 
Allan Howies | 483040.867, 8066200.614
```

It runs now but the point is not the midpoint but the start of each road (all segments grouped by 'Road').

```
SELECT Road, AsText(Line_Interpolate_Point(CSC_Roads.geometry, 0.5)) as Road_Location,
       Line_Interpolate_Point(CSC_Roads.geometry, 0.5)
FROM CSC_Roads
GROUP BY road
```

[image: result]

Comment: The error is due to the space in the column alias `Road Location`, try  `Road_Location` or putting quotes around it.

Comment: @MBain Thanks -it runs now but it creates a point for the start of the road and not the mid-point? also do you know how to get the text to just have the x,y value? see updated question.

Comment: @Taras That worked for me {SELECT Road, ST_EndPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0,0.5)), concat((ST_X(ST_EndPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0,0.5)))),',',ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0,0.5)))) as Mid_Point from CSC_Roads group by road} Now I just need to format the number to 2 decimal places.

Comment: @taras thanks...happy to accept if you post as answer. Why use endpoint (not startpoint) and why (geometry, 0,0.5)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume there is a layer called `"line"` (blue), see image below.

[image: input]

---

So, the vital thing, there must be a distinction between [**Centroid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) and [**Midpoint**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint). There several articles available online, for instance, I personally would consider this one [Mathematics: What is the difference between midpoint, center and centroid?](https://www.quora.com/Mathematics-What-is-the-difference-between-midpoint-center-and-centroid).

My personal distinction in terms of the GIS would be

[image: idea]

---

For selecting the line's middle point it is not enough just using [`ST_Centroid()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html). Because (as described in manual) it is computed as the weighted length of each line segment. Therefore, with the following query

```sql
SELECT st_centroid(geometry)
FROM "line"
```

the line geocentoid is the location of the arithmetic mean of weighted properties, see image below.

[image: result_1]

So, IMHO the most suitable solution in getting the line's middle point can be achieved by means of [`ST_Line_Substring()`](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Line_Substring.html), that produces a part of the input line geometry as a fraction between starting and ending points (`0 ≤ fraction ≤ 1`).

Thus, with the following query

```sql
SELECT ST_EndPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0,0.5))
FROM "line"

----- where 0 is a fraction where to start
----- and 0.5 is a fraction where to finish
```

the line middle point is now the middle of the line's original geometry, see image below.

[image: result_2]

Going further, the same output can be achieved with a slightly adjusted query

```sql
SELECT ST_StartPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0.5,1))
FROM "line"
```

So, it is possible to use `ST_StartPoint()` as well, an answer to the question *"Why use endpoint (not startpoint) and why (geometry, 0,0.5)?"* from comments.

So basically, `ST_EndPoint()` was used for the starting line segment and `ST_StartPoint()` for the ending line segment.

---

For extracting line's middle point coorinates, it is possible by the usage of [`ROUND()`](https://w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp), [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html). Check the following query

```sql
SELECT '(' || ROUND(ST_X(ST_StartPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0.5,1))),2) || ', ' || ROUND(ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(ST_Line_Substring(geometry,0.5,1))),2) || ')' AS XY
FROM "line"
```

---

**References:**

- [Finding middle point (midpoint) of line in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58079/finding-middle-point-midpoint-of-line-in-qgis)

Comment: Not OP wanted to say this was an excellent answer and I learned something new about definitions of "middle point". Thank you, Taras!

Comment: @she_weeds, always welcome 