# QGIS with callouts with offset from feature

Tags: qgis, labeling, callout, anchor-point

I created callouts with expression below, because I need to have anchor dropdown at the half of a line.

make_line (
make_point (
"auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx",
"auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"
),
line_interpolate_point(
$geometry,
length ($geometry)/2
)
)

However, I sometimes need to move labels a bit without showing a callout. If I use callout option, it is possible to achieve it with a setting of an offset from feature and label area (picture). How can I achieve it if I created callouts with an expression? As is seen on pictures 2 (label not manually moved) and pictures 3 ((label manually moved) I only moved label along the line.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please define the cases in which you would need to callout line to not to be visible.

Comment: I need callout to be not visible when I move label along the line (with some small margin. because manually I am not able to move label "just" along the line, I always also move label "closer" or "away" line. . When I move label away from the line, I need callout to be visible. Therefore I originally used offset from feature (line), because then to some extent callout is not visible.

Comment: Then I suggest you compare the azimuth of your callout line to the azimuth of the line feature.

Comment: Can you advise how to compare azimuths? Also how to assign correct callouts to correct lines when comparing?

Comment: You should be able to get the azimuths using the corresponding expression, then substract them, then define a threshold below which you don't want labels to show.

Comment: I understand. I don´t know where is stored geometry information about callouts and how to automatically assign correct line do callout (in order to compare azimuths).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124994/discussion-between-pazelvak-and-erik).