# Select lines hanving their centroid inside a polygon, PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

How can I select a line having the centroid inside a polygon? there is a specific fuction?

Comment: Can be also useful: [Getting the line middle point with SQL in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/333237/99589)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a standard [`ST_Intersects`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html) filter, and then you have three options:

- use the [`ST_Centroid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) to get the **(weighted) centroid** of the lines:

  ```
  SELECT ln.*
  FROM   <lines> AS ln
  JOIN   <polygons> AS pl
    ON   ST_Intersects(pl.geom, ST_Centroid(ln.geom))
  ;
  ```
- use the [`ST_PointOnSurface`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) to get a **(non-weighted) center point** of the lines

```
  SELECT ln.*
  FROM   <lines> AS ln
  JOIN   <polygons> AS pl
    ON   ST_Intersects(pl.geom, ST_PointOnSurface(ln.geom))
  ;
```

- use the **interpolated midpoint** ([`ST_LineInterpolatePoint`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html)) of the lines

  ```
  SELECT ln.*
  FROM   <lines> AS ln
  JOIN   <polygons> AS pl
    ON   ST_Intersects(pl.geom, ST_LineInterpolatePoint(ln.geom, 0.5))
  ;
  ```

Depending on your lines, all three may differ:

- `ST_Centroid` results in a point not guaranteed to be on the line (check the example in the docs) and is likely not what you want
- `ST_PointOnSurface` is extended in PostGIS to work on arbitrary geometries and guarantees<sup>[</sup>*<sup>]</sup> a point on the line around the geometric center using a deterministic algorithm
- `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` generates a point on the line at the given fraction of line length (`0.5` for the midpoint) and guarantees<sup>[</sup>*<sup>]</sup> a point on the line

---

<sup>[</sup>*<sup>]</sup> <sub>within the margin of floating point rounding errors</sub>