# Splitting vectors in half using QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, splitting, polyline-creation, equal-length

I have a selection of vectors in QGIS (about 1000) that I'd like to split in half at once. I've already used the `v.split` from GRASS but as the length of links are very different one from another, I couldn't find a proper value for the *'maximum segment length'*.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: are you trying to split polygons or lines ?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *Geometry by Expression* tool with this expression:

```
collect_geometries(
    line_substring($geometry, 0, $length/2),
    line_substring($geometry, $length/2, $length)
)
```

The output is a multipart geometry, so run *Multipart to Singleparts* tool on it.

Result:

[image]

From the Help panel of the expression editor:

> ##### function line_substring
>
> Returns the portion of a line (or curve) geometry which falls between the specified start and end distances (measured from the beginning of the line). Z and M values are linearly interpolated from existing values.
>
> **Syntax**
> line_substring(geometry,start_distance,end_distance)
>
> **Arguments**
> *geometry*      - a linestring or curve geometry
> *start_distance* - distance to start of substring
> *end_distance*   - distance to end of substring

Answer (score 2):

### For Polylines

There is a possibility of using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`

Let's assume there is a layer called *'route'*, see the image below.

[image: input]

With the following Query, it is possible *to split it in half at once.*

```sql
SELECT "id", ST_Line_Substring(geometry, 0, 0.5) AS geom
FROM "route"
UNION ALL
SELECT "id", ST_Line_Substring(geometry, 0.5, 1) AS geom
FROM "route"
```

Now, the output Virtual Layer will look as follows

[image: result]

---

### For Polygons

Check this thread: [Splitting polygon into equal area polygons using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/321021/splitting-polygon-into-equal-area-polygons-using-qgis)

---

**References:**

- [Getting the line middle point with SQL in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333228/getting-the-line-middle-point-with-sql-in-qgis)