# Creating point at line end using QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, line, points-to-line

For an examination of a local power grid, I need to mark the transformation stations (substation) by simply create a point for each station.

What I want to do is that QGIS creates a point at the end of a line automatically.

How can I get there?

[image: example]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a possibility using a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...`.

Let's assume there is a polyline layer called *'polylines'* (blue lines).

[image: input]

With the following query, it is possible to create a point at the end of each line.

```sql
SELECT
    st_endpoint(geometry), *
FROM
    "polylines"
```

The output point layer (yellow) with its attribute table will look like

[image: output]

Mind the difference between [`ST_StartPoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_StartPoint.html) and [`ST_EndPoint()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html). Basically, what @TeddyTedTed meant by *Which one you need will depend on the direction of the line*.

Answer (score 15):

In the Processing Toolbox use the `Extract Specific Vertices` tool, for the `Vertex indices` use `0` for the first vertex and `-1` for the last vertex. Which one you need will depend on the direction of the line.

EDIT: Apologies, I didn't read your question properly, you said automatically. If it's just for display purposed you could use a geometry generator symbology to show a point at the end of the line using  `end_point($geometry)` as the expression. If you need to create an actual data point automatically every time a line is created then I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: An additional good point for this answer is that is also gives the value of angle of the segment of the line, i.e. azimuth.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the processing tool "Geometry by Expression" and either use `start_point($geometry)` or `end_point($geometry)` as expression.

If you want them for display purposes only, you can use these expression within layersymbology and add an geometry generator.

Answer (score 4):

Another example using pyqgis:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

def find_endpoint(feat):
    for item in feat.geometry().vertices(): #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator
        pass
    return QgsPointXY(item)

ends = [find_endpoint(f) for f in layer.getFeatures()]

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "endpoints", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()
for e in ends:
    g = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(e)
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(g)
    provider.addFeature(f)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution could be:

Using Vector ‣ Geometry Tools ‣ Extract verticas. Afterwards simply delete  all points but thoose which were generated at the end and beginning.

Comment: What if you have thousands of lines and each has at least 1000 vertices in each?

Answer (score 3):

Additionally, I may suggest using PyQGIS, tested on QGIS 3.10.4-A Coruña.

Let's assume there is a line layer `'lines'`, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` and paste the script below

```py
# providing the polyline layer's name
layer_name = "line"

# accessing the line layer by name
try:
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
except IndexError:
    raise ValueError("The layer {} does not exist.".format(layer_name))

# creating an empty point layer for output
point_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "End Points", "memory")
provider = point_layer.dataProvider()

# detecting layer wkb and wkb type
layer_wkb = layer.wkbType() # integer
layer_wkb_type = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(layer_wkb) # string

# checking geometry type of the layer
if layer.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString: # getting end points for each part of a MultiLineString layer geometry type
    print("Your layer is a {}-geometry type".format(layer_wkb_type))
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        multi_geom = feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()
        for part in multi_geom:
            end_point = QgsPoint(part[-1])
            f = QgsFeature()
            f.setGeometry(end_point)
            provider.addFeature(f)

elif layer.wkbType() == QgsWkbTypes.LineString: # getting end points for a LineString layer geometry type
    print("Your layer is a {}-geometry type".format(layer_wkb_type))
    for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        geom = feature.geometry().asPolyline()
        end_point = QgsPoint(geom[-1])
        f = QgsFeature()
        f.setGeometry(end_point)
        provider.addFeature(f)

else: # other layer geometry types are not accepted
    print("Your layer is a {}-geometry type, when only 'LineString' or 'MultiLineString' is accepted".format(layer_wkb_type))

# adding a new layer to the map
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(point_layer)
```

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like

[image: output]

---

**References:**

- [Can vector layer get start point and end point of line using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/can-vector-layer-get-start-point-and-end-point-of-line-using-pyqgis/)
- [First and last point of MultiLineString-objects in QGIS 3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304755/how-to-get-first-and-last-point-of-multilinestring-objects-in-qgis3)

Answer (score 3):

Another approach via `RMB > Duplicate Layer`.

Then for a new layer by means of ["Geometry Generator"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/symbol_selector.html#the-geometry-generator) apply `RMB > Properties > Symbology > Geometry Generator` as *Point/MultiPoint*. This will be for display purposes only.

[image: output]

If you are using "Geometry by Expression" from processing toolbox this is not for display purposes only. It creates the geometry as new layer.