# Select points at the end of a line

Tags: qgis, point, line, filter

I have two layers in QGIS:

1. "line" layer which consists of lines and multi-lines
2. "Point" with points with attribute 'Code'

How to write a efficient script in PyQGIS to find out all the lines at whose

- start point, there is a point with Code value "1" and
- end point, there is a point with Code value "1"

[image]

Comment: Dear Rajesh Patnaik, I have seen your comment to @MBain answer, unfortunately it is not typical on GIS SE to request directly from a user some Python code without demonstrating any efforts of coding. It seems to me that your Question will be probably closed because of the missing attempts. So, I am highly suggesting to provide some code trials, otherwise  MBain's answer looks valid to me.

Comment: Maybe these threads [Creating point at line end using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347762/creating-point-at-line-end-using-qgis) or [Can vector layer get start point and end point of line using PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/208831/can-vector-layer-get-start-point-and-end-point-of-line-using-pyqgis) can help you to unravel your issue in a Python way.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a *Virtual Layer* `Layer|Add Layer|Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` with the Query:

```sql
SELECT L.*
FROM "LineLayer" AS L, "PointLayer" AS P1, "PointLayer" AS P2
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_PointN(L.geometry, -1), P1.geometry)
AND ST_Intersects(ST_PointN(L.geometry, 1), P2.geometry)
AND P1."Code" = 1
AND P2."Code" = 1
```

You would need to substitute "LineLayer" and "PointLayer" with the correct layer names.

This will select all the lines where the start point `ST_PointN(L.geometry, 1)` and end point `ST_PointN(L.geometry, -1)` each intersect points in the "PointLayer" where the "Code=1".

Comment: Thanks.
Can you please write it in python to run it in python console?

Comment: I'm afraid not, SQL is more my strong point than Python. Good luck

Comment: To be more precise with points I may be using `ST_Equals()` instead

Comment: @Taras, Thanks, didn't think of `ST_Equals()`

Comment: BTW, in VL you can also use `start_point()` as well as `end_point()`